# Fiil an array with buttons

Tags: java

```
private Button[] Minefiled={g_btn2,g_btn3.....};
private Button g_btnNew;
private Button g_btn2;
private Button g_btn3;
private Button g_btn4;
private Button g_btn5;
private Button g_btn6;
private Button g_btn7;
```

Can i fill an array with buttons like this?

Comment: why don't you try and tell us the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make an array of buttons, but you should probably decide between having them in an array and having them each with a different variable name.  Something like

```
private Button[]mineField;
classconstructor()
{
    mineField = new Button[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        mineField[x] = new Button(--button type here--);
}
```

Comment: (--button type here--); what are you meen Button type

Comment: a better implementation would be to store only the button's id's in the array, then getting the instance of the button just when you need it in your code using findViewById(button[position]). just thinking about storing a thousand Button objects makes me shiver.

Comment: The Button constructor [requires](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) arguments.  Also note that if your design requires an array of buttons, there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to store buttons in an array. To parse a button, you need to use the following code: ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)); What you need to do here is getting the id's and store them in an array and use a loop to control every buttons.

Example:

```
int[] myButtons = new int[] {
    R.id.button1,
    R.id.button2,
    R.id.button3,
    R.id.button4,
    R.id.button5,
};

for(int i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++){
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(myButtons[i]);
    button.setText("This is button " + (i + 1));
}
```